# Delete data in CSV until a row contains x, then add headers

Tags: python

[image]

So i want to delete everything up to START-OF-DATA, or just move the CSV into a Data frame at the row after START-OF-DATA and then add headers.  The google-fu shows me how to add headers but dynamically having python do: "ignore everything until readings from 1--> until you run into a row that says START-OF-DATA then also ignore that row and start at the row below it." Can't seem to find that.

I'm thinking maybe add it all to a data frame then possibly remove rows until it finds START-OF-DATA value

Comment: Does it have to be python? `sed -n '/START-OF-DATA/,$p' oldfile > newfile` will remove everything before `START-OF-DATA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5']

with open('input.csv') as fp:
    for row in fp:
        if row.startswith('START-OF-DATA'):
            break
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=None, names=cols)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Col1  Col2  Col3     Col4    Col5
0  All Curncy     0     3  Albania  101.18
```

Export:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.csv") as infile:
    # skip over all lines until START-OF-DATA
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("START-OF-DATA"):
            break
    # write the rest to the output file
    with open("newfilename.csv", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write("new header line\n")
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```